# Getting complete disassembly of an executable binary

Tags: macos, gdb, disassembly, otool

Is it possible to get a complete disassembly (which can act as input to an assembler) of an executable?

When I use `otool -tV a.out` I get to see only the text section. Other sections like data aren't visible.

When I use `gdb`, the disassemble command requires a start and an end address. However I do not know how to find out the start and the end address of a binary (say a.out).

I'm trying to disassemble an executable, tinker with the assembly code and then reassemble it.
Is that possible?

It'd also help if one can find out the names of all the sections in a binary.

Answer (score 40):

Try using this command, i remember using it sometime back:

```
otool -tvV a.out
```

Comment: This command helped me a lot in the past as well as `otool -IvV a.out` (displays the indirect symbol table). Furthermore there is the _-d_ switch for information on the _data_ section. More info in: `man otool`

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, you can install (possibly by homebrew) binutils that includes gobjdump. You can disassemble any binary program once installed. It's open and free.

Comment: This should be a comment since it dies not attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Hopper Disassembler](http://www.hopperapp.com/)

quote:

> Hopper is a reverse engineering tool for the Mac, that lets you disassemble, decompile and debug your 32/64bits Intel Mac executables.

It costs $59, but you can download a demo to check if it gets the job done first.

**EDIT**

It seems you can achieve this with `otool` as well, according to [the manual](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-698/man/otool.1).

> .B -d
> Display the contents of the (_^_DATA,_^_data) section.

Also have a look at [this short blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120401144155/http://divine-protection.com/wordpress/?p=15) (archive link, original is gone) that describes the mentioned use of `otool`, and how you can use `objdump` as mentioned by @Sjlver.

Comment: `otool -d` certainly displays the data section. But that is not all. If the executable calls a method like: `printf("ABCD")`, I can't find the declaration of the string "ABCD" in the assembly anywhere.

Comment: I am looking for a free solution. So didn't give it a shot.

Comment: This should be a comment since it does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @jww How does this not attempt to answer the question?

Answer (score -5):

On linux, you can try to use `objdump -D myprog`

Note that this will work only if the program does not contain irregular control flow. Especially malware is often obfuscated, e.g. by inserting spurious bytes that are then jumped over.

If you're targeting this kind of programs, I've heard that one of the best products to use is [IDA pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml).

Comment: This should be a comment since it does not attempt to answer the question.